# How to reference other .yaml files of hydra conf folder?

Tags: python, hydra, fb-hydra

My conf directory looks like:

```
conf
- hydra
 - run
   - dir
    - job_timestamp.yaml
main.yaml
```

in main.yaml I am trying to overwrite the hydra output directory with a custom structure as defined in job_timestamp.yaml:

```
dir: ./outputs/${status}/${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}
```

However, writing:

```
hydra:
  run:
    dir: job_timestamp
```

in main.yaml doesn't reference the hydra/run/dir/job_timestamp.yaml file I have - it actually just makes the output folder name "job_timestamp"

I was wondering how I would reference my job_timestamp.yaml file in main.yaml to overwrite hydra's output directory config.

EDIT:
I originally had hydra/run/dir: job_timestamp under defaults of main.yaml, however, it would return with hydra/run/dir not found in defaults list. I am planning to have different versions of main.yaml (e.g. main2.yaml, evaluate.yaml etc.) which all would need to override the output directory with the same format, is there a way to do this so that it is DRY?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing basic concepts in Hydra like config values and config groups.
You do not "reference" a config file from a config value, only from the defaults list.

Go back to the basic tutorial and make sure you understand config groups.
Hydra specific config groups are defined inside the Hydra package ([here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/tree/main/hydra/conf)). You may want to override Hydra configs via config groups - but I only suggest you attempt that after you have a better understanding of config groups.
In the mean time, you can do it by simply overriding it directly in your main.yaml file:

`main.yaml`:

```yaml
hydra:
  run:
    dir: outputs/${status}/${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}
```

Comment: ah ok, Thank you! I originally had `hydra/run/dir: job_timestamp` under defaults of main.yaml, however, it would return with hydra/run/dir not found in defaults list. I am planning to have different versions of main.yaml (e.g. main2.yaml, evaluate.yaml etc.) which all would need to override the output directory with the same format, is there a way to do this so that it is DRY?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I suggest you ask another question.